# How does one calculate the expected value?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose a fair coin is flipped twice. Define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ , where $X$ counts the number of heads, and $Y$ counts the number of tails, in the two flips.

1. Evaluate $\Bbb E(X), \Bbb E(Y)$.
2. From these values, can you decide whether $X$ and $Y$ are dependent or independent?

Comment: You should be able to compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ directly from the definition in this case.

Comment: Please useTex to type for your next post.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören thankyou. i will work on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These expected values will be the same if the coin is fair and the two flips are independent. For example X=2 for HH only, X=1 for HT and TH, and X=0 for TT only. That gives 2*(1/4)+1*(1/2)+0*(1/4)=1 for E(X). If you do it, E(Y) also comes out 1.

But from these *alone* one cannot conclude whether X,Y are independent, and they are not, since given X=2 it *must* be that Y=0.

Comment: thankyou @coffeemath.
now in order to find the E(XY), do i simply just use this **E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)** formula?
and so in this case E(XY) is going to come out as 1, which makes it independent?

Comment: @ArsalAbbas No the formula E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) may *only* be used if you already know X and Y are independent. In fact that formula is used as the *definition* of independence. What you have to do is to find the product XY for each of the four cases HH HT TH TT which are in the sample space, which are respectively 2*0,1*1,1*1,and 0*2 so that the expected value of XY would be  1*(1/4)+1*(1/4)=1/2. With this calculation, we note E(XY) is *not* equal to the product E(X)E(Y) in this example, ergo the two variables are not independent by the definition given above.

Comment: I recently asked a related question, and found out that the expected value equation, if true, is the definition of when $X,Y$ are "uncorrelated". It turns out the definition of "independent" is different from that, but note that (independent) implies (uncorrelated) [not conversely]

Comment: thank you for taking out your time to explain this to me. i really appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

$$E(X) = E(Y) = 1$$

You cannot say $$E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$$ implies independence. You need to check the conditional probabilities to be sure.

Comment: But if $\mathbb{E}[XY]\neq \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ then you know the random variables are not independent.

Comment: Yes that is correct and in this case the number of heads determines the number of tails

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of X is 1, because the theoretical probability of X is 1/2, and vice versa for Y. 
As for deciding whether X and Y are independent or not, they are independent because the expected value of X is 1/2 and the expected value of Y is 1/2 and there is no overlap in probability and getting heads or tails does not affect the later outcome.

Answer (score 1):

So our sample space is

S={HH, HT, TH, TT}, where H=Heads and T=Tails.

The probabilities of *X* being 0, 1 and 2 are:
P(X=0)=1/4 ; P(X=1)=2/4 ; P(X=2)=1/4

Similarly we have *Y* as:
P(Y=0)=1/4 ; P(Y=1)=2/4 ; P(Y=2)=1/4

The expected value of the probability X is:
$$E(X)=\sum_{i=0}^3 xP(X=x) = 0(1/4) + 1(2/4) + 2(1/4) = 1$$

And the same goes for E(Y)=1.

Lastly, we can conclude that X and Y are in fact dependant. Because if, say, X=1 we know for a fact that Y *must* be 1, etc.